# How can I open a listfragment from normal activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I search here but I don't find any answer that work with my code. That I'm trying to do is open a listfragment from my mainActivity. I want that the listFragment appear when the user press an icon in the action bar.

Thanks in advance

Code where I try to launch the listFragment:

```
 if (id == R.id.action_favourites) {
        ListFragment newFragment = new ListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.favourites_fragment, newFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
```

Custom row in the listfragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/favourites_fragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newspaperNameFavourite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/passUrl"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML of the listview of the listFragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

This is my listFragment class:

```
public class FavouritesActionBar extends ListFragment {


    private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "color";
    private static final String INDEX = "index";

    private String title;
    private int page;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private AdRequest adRequest;
    private DataBaseWrapper dataBase;


    public static Favourites newInstance(int color, String title) {

        Favourites fragment = new Favourites();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, color);
        bundle.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        dataBase = new DataBaseWrapper(getContext());

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = null;
        final String[] name;
        final String[] url;

        dataBase.getAllData();

        name = new String[dataBase.getAllData().size()];
        url = new String[dataBase.getAllData().size()];

        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> map;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataBase.getAllData().size(); i++) {
            name[i] = dataBase.getAllData().get(i).getName();
            url[i] = dataBase.getAllData().get(i).getUrl();

            rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name", name[i]);
            map.put("url", url[i]);
            list.add(map);

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.favourites, new String[] { "name", "url" }, new int[] { R.id.newspaperNameFavourite, R.id.passUrl });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id){
        TextView tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.passUrl);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Webview.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("_url", tv2.getText().toString());
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are misusing the word "launch", you mean "replace"?

Comment: ok, thanks. But how can I add the container ID in the xml to works fine this code?

Comment: I've usually used an empty `FrameLayout` for my Fragment container. I've never used a `RelativeLayout` or any layout with contents

Comment: I can replace the label RelativeLayout to FrameLayout and its work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just replace a fragment using `FragmentTransition.replace()`?

Comment: It's also not clear if you are using a custom `ListFragment` that you defined or the Android provided one.

Comment: No, That I'm trying to do is open a fragment that, in this case, is a ListFragment. I want to open a class that is a listfragment when press an icon in the actionBar

Comment: I think you understand the icon-click part, as evident by `if (id == R.id.action_favourites)`. What currently happens when you click the button? Does the RelativeLayout get replaced with your fragment, or not?

Comment: What happens when you click the button is that you open the listFragment (i want to open the fragment like a new screen). Maybe the xml is wrong... But I don't know how can I open the listfragment when click the button. This is all that I want. Click the button and open the listFragment

Comment: If you want the fragment to open in a new screen, you should create a new activity with this listFragment, and then open that activity via intent when you click on the action bar icon. If what you want is to replace the content of the current activity with the listFragment, just use FragmentTransition.replace() as @cricket_007 said

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've updated my question with my listfragment class. Please, can you give some example code??

Comment: If you want your fragment class, then why are you doing `ListFragment newFragment = new ListFragment()`? You should be doing `FavouritesActionBar newFragment = new FavouritesActionBar()`

Comment: If I do that you said I have this error in newFragment (fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.favourites_fragment, newFragment);): Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.exagon.goalnews.FavouritesActionBar', required: 'android.app.Fragment' less...

Comment: Looks like you are importing `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: I put the imports correctly. But I'm not be able to open the ListFragment

Comment: Don't do nothing and don't give me any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

1: Create a new activity.
2: Paste this in the new activity in OnCreate:

```
 Fragment fr = new FavouritesActionBar();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

3:In the xml of your new activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
    android:name="com.yourpackage.FavouritesActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

4: In your MainActivity in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourNewActivityCreateInPoint1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```